# Angular Change Detection in HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I have an `HttpClient` service which is updating the data at backend. During the processing at backend, I' am displaying a loading state by doing `this.isLoading = true`, and after the successfully processing, I' am removing that loading state in `subscribe()` by using `this.isLoading = false;`.

Now I changed my code to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and the loading state is not vanishing anymore. I know the change detection in `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` occurs when an `input` property is changed or when an object reference is changed during an event on component etc.

In my case, do I have to manually call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to trigger change detection or am I missing something?

**Edit**

Just to clear, I' am using `this.isLoading` to show/hide loading state by adding/removing class on an HTML element accordingly. For example,

`<div [class.processing]="isLoading"></div>`

Comment: Does the component recieve @Input() from an other component ?, if not remove `ChangeDetection.OnPush()` o you can use `async` pipe.

Comment: @JSingh, thanks for commenting. No the component didn't receive `@Input`, it maintains a local variable `isLoading` (boolean) to show/hide loading state. I think `async` won't work with boolean? I have updated the question, please view again.

Comment: If the component didn't receive @Input then it won't trigger the changes. Can you post your template

Comment: @JSingh, just updated the question. Please see the updated one. Thanks.

Comment: Try changing `[class.processing]` to `<div [ngClass]="{'processing': isLoading}"></div>`

Comment: Same effect. They are essentially the same. This has something to do with change detection not getting triggered in `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush, change detection will run ONLY when an input has changed. Since you are subscribing to an observable and changing a local variable, angular will not be notified of this change so you have to let it know yourself. 
The recommended way is to use ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck() which will perform change detection on the tree branch above your component

[image]

There is more is more info on this in this [great thoughtram article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#observables)

And an excellent [presentation here by Pascal Precht](https://pascalprecht.github.io/slides/angular-2-change-detection-explained)